# Getting hibernate session on a shared entity manager proxy gives back the same proxy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-orm

In our **Spring Boot 1.5** project, we were using **Spring ORM 5.3.3**, **Hibernate 5.0.12**

To get the session, we had this utility class that uses entity manager to get the current session

The entity manager that gets injected here is ***Shared Entity Manager Proxy***

```
@Component
public class EntityListenerUtil {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityListenerUtil() {
    }

    public EntityManager getCurrentEntityManager() {
        return this.entityManager;
    }

    public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
        Session session = this.getCurrentSession();
        return session.getTransaction();
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return getCurrentEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
    }
}
```

When we started using **spring boot 2.4.2**, it pulled in the same **Spring ORM 5.3.3** and **Hibernate 5.4.27**
The same code when ran now gives back the same shared entity manager proxy bean the `entityManager` field contains instead of giving the session implementation (SessionImpl for example)

The difference is that hibernate 5.0.12 [Session](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0.12/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/Session.java#L75) does not extend **EntityManager** but 5.4.27 [Session](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.4.27/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/Session.java#L86) does.

The use of EntityManager shouldn't alter the behavior of fetching Session with the **unwrap** method with hibernate version change.

Spring ORM [SharedEntityManagerCreator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/SharedEntityManagerCreator.java#L248) checks if the type we want to unwrap is an instance of the same proxy and if so, it returns back the same proxy. That condition was returning `false` before as Hibernate 5.0.12 Session didn't extend EntityManager but the new one does.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Why are you using the Session?

Comment: The `Session` is the `EntityManager` in newer version of Hibernate which is why you get the same object. It shouldn't matter as you already have the session. (which is generally not needed with the current state of JPA).

Comment: What is the actual problem here? What stopped working for you after the upgrade?

Comment: Using `(AbstractSessionImpl)this.getCurrentEntityManager().unwrap(AbstractSessionImpl.class)` solved the problem.

@crizzis problem is that in Hibernate 5.4 Session extends EntityManager. So in our case, since entity manager I receive is a shared proxy, Spring shared entity manager creator checks if the class I am trying to get is instance of same proxy, if it is same, it returns back the proxy itself. so in my case, when I use Session.class, it returns back the same shared entity manager but I was getting SessionImpl before with old hibernate. I fixed it now using AbstractSessionImpl

Comment: And the problem is that if I get back the shared entity manager itself instead of session impl, I cannot get current transaction as it throws this error `Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager`